# array_key_exists Cyryllic characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, internationalization

Can't get this to work with Cyrillic characters:

```
if (array_key_exists($list['fname'], $data)) {

}
```

Array keys are Cyrillic characters

Please help

Comment: $array = array('кирилица' => true);
var_dump(array_key_exists('кирилица', $array));
returns boolean true

Comment: but this will not solve the problem as keys can't be matched

Comment: so, did either of the utf-8 answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are all the cyrillic characters working otherwise? It seems it's probably over-runing the character set -- by default php is ansii, if I remember right. You need UTF-8.

In any case, put this at the top of that php file and see if that helps:

```
<?php
   ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$list['fname']` is coming form mysql make sure you use UTF-8 charset and utf8_general_ci as collation. If its hard coded, save your php file as UTF-8.

Also you can always use a hash for the text as key.

Comment: just checked for some reason fname is not being read from database and table is utf8_general_ci